# How to check whether the needed Windows API function is available on the system where an application is running?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, dynamic-loading

I want to use some Windows API functions specific to the latest *Windows 10* versions. E.g. functions like [`CreatePseudoConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createpseudoconsole) supporting [*Windows Pseudo Console* (ConPTY)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/) were introduced only in *Windows 10 version 1809* (the fall update of *Windows 10* released in 2018).

- The classic approach is to load Windows kernel dynamic library where the needed functions are implemented (using [`LoadLibrary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) function) and to check every needed function via [`GetProcAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) call.
- The newer approach introduced in *Visual C++ 6.0* is called [*Delay Loading*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls).

Is there any modern (simple, clear, and transparent) way to check what parts of Windows API are available for a running application? Or is it a way to check what is an exact *Windows 10* version an application is running on? I want to use functions like `CreatePseudoConsole()` only if they are available (if they are not available some other code should be executed).

Comment: The MSDN documentation is quite clear on this. They have gone out of their way to make it hard for you to check version number. Try to obtain the API. Call `GetProcAddress`. If the function is available, you will get it. If not, `NULL` will be returned. That is how to do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Somehow words `Visual C++ 6.0` and `newer` refuse to cooperate in my mind.

Comment: Conceptually I'd argue against checking for API availability at all. You app either needs it - and than you state a minimum version as a requirement - or it does not, and than you do not bother to check. Otherwise you end up with application offering different features to the user without them having a clue why it's behaving in seemingly random way.

Comment: Installer should check that required DLL's are present.

Comment: @SergeyA You are right in general but in my case some application feature may work better with the latest Windows API functions (but it also works fine without them). And I don't want to restrict Windows OS support to the two latest Windows 10 releases only to make this application feature working better.

Comment: @stark Do you mean `kernel32.dll` (where `CreatePseudoConsole()` function is implemented)? It is present always on Windows, it is a kernel DLL.

Comment: @stark We are talking about having the program attempt to use the new API, but implement fall back behaviour if it is not available. Nothing at all to do with installation.

Comment: @SergeyA Bad advice. Either asker demands that users have 1809 or later, pretty restrictive. Or, you choose to eschew the functionality for years until all target users have 1809. Approaches that are easy for the developer, but impact on the user.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I disagree, and I already explained my reasoning. We can have difference of opinions on that, I imagine.

Comment: @SergeyA Your logic is flawed though. You don't necessarily end up with different features. You might end up with performance differences, but the same functionality. And you'd prefer to deny performance benefits to the user? I doubt it. And if you do have functionality differences, why should the user not have a clue. These things can be documented. Or a dialog box popped up to explain it. Anyway, good luck trying to sell software for money which only runs on the a version of Windows released 6 months ago!!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan obviously we come from a very different backgrounds, so I see no point in discussing further.

Comment: [Why can't I use the linker to delay-load a function from kernel32?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100201-00/?p=15123)

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your useful link!

Answer (score 2):

`GetProcAddress()` is the only way to do what you are asking for.  Definitely DO NOT rely on detecting the OS version (in recent Windows versions, it gets increasingly more difficult to do that reliably), DO rely on whether the desired function(s) actually exist instead.

Even a linker's [delay-load feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls) uses `GetProcAddress()` internally. In this case, you can use a [delay-load notification hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/error-handling-and-notification) to determine the result of the load so you can flag your code accordingly for later checks, or even supply a pointer to an alternative fallback function if needed.

This last part is important, because a delay-loaded function is not loaded until it is called for the first time, so if you call a delay-loaded function that does not exist at runtime, and a notification hook does not provide an alternative function, your code will likely crash trying to execute a function via a NULL pointer.  To avoid that, you can just call `GetProcAddress()` explicitly before making any calls to the function.

Answer (score 2):

If the API belongs to an API set, [it's recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/detect-api-set-availability) to use [IsApiSetImplemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/apiquery2/nf-apiquery2-isapisetimplemented) instead of `GetProcAddress()`.

> The traditional approach for testing whether a Win32 API is available is to use LoadLibrary or GetProcAddress. However, these are not a reliable means for testing API sets because of the reverse forwarding support in Windows 10.

> To identify whether a particular Win32 API belongs to an API set, review the requirements table in the reference documentation for the API.